# Is there a way to check for changes in Python Tk windows?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a program that changes the location of objects on a tkinter canvas, depending on the size of the window. This works, but it is run every loop and slows down the program dramatically when there are lots of objects, as it deletes and re-draws them.

Is there a way to check for changes in the size of a window, so that it only has to be run once, when it needs to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the window size changes (and for other reasons), tkinter will fire a `<Configure>` event. You can bind to this event to get notified when the widget changes size.

From the official documentation:

> A Configure event is sent to a window whenever its size, position, or border width changes, and sometimes when it has changed position in the stacking order.

Note: this is true for all widgets, not just the root window. For instance,  you can bind to the canvas widget or any other widget.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, width=20)
label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

def handle_configure(event):
    text="window geometry:\n" + root.geometry()
    label.configure(text=text)

root.bind("<Configure>", handle_configure)

root.mainloop()
```

You must be careful not to change the size of the widget from within the bound function or you may end up in an infinite loop as the event will be triggered when the widget resizes, which resizes the widget, which causes the event to be triggered, ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use `w.winfo_height()` `w.winfo_width()` method to get the current height and width of `w` in pixels.(`w` can be any widget of any type. )

e.g.

```
from Tkinter import *
w=Tk()
w.geometry('400x600')

w.update()

print (w.winfo_width())
print (w.winfo_height())
```